# Dramatic failure vs success

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e

I'm reading through my (new) World  of Darkness [which was rebranded to  Chronicles of Darkness 1st Edition] core book re-learning how to play so I can start planning a campaign for my friends. I can't find an example of what happens when a 1 is a dramatic failure and an 8 to 10 is a success.

For example, if I roll 5 dice and get a 1, 3, 5, 8, 9, do I get 2 successes and a dramatic failure, or does the 1 counter a success giving me 1 success?

Comment: Are you sure that you are speaking about [tag:World-of-Darkness] (old), not Chronicles of Darkness?

Comment: its the blue one, says world of darkness on the cover, goes with vampire the requim etc, wasn't aware they changed it to chronicles.

Comment: Requiem is nWoD, aka CoD. The dice system of WoD and CoD is not the same at all. now: 1st or 2nd Edition?aka: Pre or Post God Machine Chronicle? (I take pre)

Comment: an example given for rolling a 1 is your gun jams. But each success would result a point of damage. so by rolling 2 successes and a 1 do I get 2 points of damage and a jam, or 1 point of damage and no jam? the two rules for successes and dramatic failures don't explain what happens if you roll a dice pool and get both situations

Comment: https://www.book-info.com/isbn/1-58846-484-9.htm this is the book i am using

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the roll you've described, you'd end up with two successes, from the 8 and the 9 you rolled. The 1 has no effect, because you garnered successes on your roll. The only time that you get a dramatic failure under these rules is if penalties have reduced your die pool to zero or below (giving you a single "chance die" to roll) and *that* die comes up a one.

The rules summary on pages 32 and 33 should give you the basic idea.